# SQL query to count unique csv in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

Say I have the following SQLite v3 table, which holds some names per each country:

```
Germany   Peter,Jan,David,Florian
USA       James,Joe,Bob,David,Alan,George
UK        George,Jack,Peter
Israel    David,Moshe,Chaim
```

The names for each country are separated using commas.

I want to count how many *unique* names there are in total, which in this case will be 12 (since e.g. David is both in Germany, USA and Israel).

Is there a direct way to do it via a SQL query?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using/targetting? Handling strings and comma-separated ones in particular is very much dependent on the actual database engine - `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or whatever else you might be using - please add an appropriate tag

Comment: SQLite (v3 of course).

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: tbh the way the data is stored is up to me - as long as the list is given within the column. Obviously in reality I have a huge data set and it has to be stored in this form.

Comment: "as long as the list is given within the column"? Why? If you had a row per name you could group by country and you could be getting whatever you need using basic SQL, you'd have much better time adding or removing names, simple distinct query would solve your issue etc. Or a separate table for name+country_id, whatever.

Comment: Because the project I'm working on is set up in such a way that this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a direct way to do it via a SQL query?

I believe that the following will produce the count of unique names directly:-

```
WITH
    splt(value,rest) AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                substr(names,1,instr(names,',')-1),
                substr(names,instr(names,',')+1)||',' 
            FROM thetable
            UNION ALL SELECT 
                substr(rest,1,instr(rest,',')-1),
                substr(rest,instr(rest,',')+1) 
            FROM splt 
            WHERE length(rest) > 0 
            LIMIT 20 /* just in case limit to 20 iterations increase if more iterations exected */
    ),
    intermediate AS 
        (
            SELECT count(*),
                group_concat(value) 
            FROM splt 
            WHERE length(value) > 0 
            GROUP BY value
        )
SELECT count(*) AS unique_names FROM intermediate;
```

**Explanation**

This assumes that the country is in a column and that the names are in another column and that the column name is **names** in a table named **thetable**

The query consists of 2 CTE's (Common Table Expressions which are basically temporary tables).

The first CTE named **splt** is recursive it extracts each name in the list as a row.

Note that a recursive CTE MUST have some means of determining when to stop iterating a WHERE clause or a LIMIT. In the case both are used the WHERE clause is the correct check ceasing the iterations (on a per source row basis) when the length of the extracted value is greater than 0. The `LIMIT 20` is a precautionary measure, of course it may be increased.

The second CTE, named **intermediate** then removes 0 length names and duplicates by grouping according to value using the result from the splt CTE.

Finally the number of remaining rows is counted.

**Demonstration**

Using the following to demonstrate:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thetable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thetable (country TEXT, names TEXT);
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES
    ('Germany','Peter,Jan,David,Florian'),
    ('USA','James,Joe,Bob,David,Alan,George'),
    ('UK','George,Jack,Peter'),
    ('Isreal','David,Moshe,Chaim'),
    /*<<<<< ADDED to test resillience*/
    ('Spain',''), 
    ('France',null),
    ('Italy',zeroblob(100))
;
WITH
    splt(value,rest) AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                substr(names,1,instr(names,',')-1),
                substr(names,instr(names,',')+1)||',' 
            FROM thetable
            UNION ALL SELECT 
                substr(rest,1,instr(rest,',')-1),
                substr(rest,instr(rest,',')+1) 
            FROM splt 
            WHERE length(rest) > 0 
            LIMIT 20 /* just in case limit to 20 iterations increase if more iterations exected */
    ),
    intermediate AS 
        (
            SELECT count(*),
                group_concat(value) 
            FROM splt 
            WHERE length(value) > 0 
            GROUP BY value
        )
SELECT count(*) AS unique_names FROM intermediate;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thetable;
```

Results in:-

[image]

Comment: Incredible! It works perfectly. Many, many thanks :)